# spring mvc request mapping inheritance

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC 3.2 app and I am trying to find the best way to handle my URLs.  I am looking to support multiple customers with something like this:

```
www.myproduct.com/customerNameX/products
www.myproduct.com/customerNameX/office/
www.myproduct.com/customerNamex/financial
www.myproduct.com/customerNamex/...
```

I would like to have a controller for each of the path after customerName.  I was hoping there was a way to do some sort of inheritance request mapping in Spring MVC.  Here is my current attempt that results in deploy errors("Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'rootController' bean method ")

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping( "/{officeId}/" )
public class RootController  {

    public @ResponseBody
    Office getOffice( @PathVariable String officeId ) {

    return offficeService.findOfficeByName(officeId);
    }
 }

@Controller
@RequestMapping( "/{officeId}/products" )
public class ProductsController  extends RootController {
...
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping( "/{officeId}/office" )
public class OfficeController  extends RootController {
...
}
```

The thought being that the root controller would get the first level requests, and the officeId would tell all other requests what officeId is being requests. But I don't think this is the correct approach.

I would really appreciate any tips on the best way to build my URL's properly.

Comment: I think it is because the method `getOffice` in RootControl is mapped twice, the solution will be is to move all the request mapping methods out of RootController to another class

Comment: 1. You don't need to extend RootController just for extending request mapping paths.  2. You need to have @RequestMapping on the handler methods; It is mandatory. Everything else is good.